# How to restore database from a copied folder in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have created a database called RateDifferenceDB in mongodb before some time.

Then I copied the folder called RateDifferenceDB from the location where it was created.

Then I format my computer, so all my data is gone.

Then I installed a fresh copy of windows and then I installed mongodb.

Now I want to restore that database called RateDifferenceDB. Is that possible?

**Wait before negative marking this question:**

I know there are commands called `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. But at the time before fomating windows, I didn't knew that.

**update:**

```
D:\Program Files\mongodb\bin>mongod --dbpath ${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDiff
erenceDB
2016-07-19T02:35:37.146-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5
012 port=27017 dbpath=${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDifferenceDB 64-bit host=Vi
shal-PC
2016-07-19T02:35:37.146-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/W
indows Server 2008 R2
2016-07-19T02:35:37.146-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
2016-07-19T02:35:37.147-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4249c1d2b59
99ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
2016-07-19T02:35:37.147-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-07-19T02:35:37.147-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-07-19T02:35:37.147-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-07-19T02:35:37.147-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-07-19T02:35:37.148-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ss
l
2016-07-19T02:35:37.148-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-07-19T02:35:37.149-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-07-19T02:35:37.149-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { db
Path: "${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDifferenceDB" } }
2016-07-19T02:35:37.150-0700 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed
errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port
) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-07-19T02:35:37.151-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets
 during startup.
2016-07-19T02:35:37.151-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

**Update2:**

I get a not found exception. Look below for more details:

```
D:\Program Files\mongodb\bin>mongod --dbpath ${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDiff
erenceDB
2016-07-19T04:37:45.927-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6
560 port=27017 dbpath=${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDifferenceDB 64-bit host=Vi
shal-PC
2016-07-19T04:37:45.927-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/W
indows Server 2008 R2
2016-07-19T04:37:45.928-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
2016-07-19T04:37:45.928-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4249c1d2b59
99ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
2016-07-19T04:37:45.928-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-07-19T04:37:45.928-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-07-19T04:37:45.928-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-07-19T04:37:45.929-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-07-19T04:37:45.930-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ss
l
2016-07-19T04:37:45.930-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-07-19T04:37:45.930-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-07-19T04:37:45.931-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { db
Path: "${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDifferenceDB" } }
2016-07-19T04:37:45.931-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndList
en: 29 Data directory ${J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup}/RateDifferenceDB not found., te
rminating
2016-07-19T04:37:45.931-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: first check if there is other instance running (as per attached log) then tell us what engine was used or list file names if you are not sure

Comment: @profesor79 How do I check if other instance is running??

Comment: Run Task Manager and check if there is any mongod in Applications, Processes or Services.

Comment: @profesor79 Yes, an instance of mongod is running. The file name is mongod.exe

Comment: stop this process and try to run your command line

Comment: @profesor79 Can you please check Update2 part of question?

Comment: --dbpath J:\Setup\Mongodb\Backup\RateDiff - andriy answer is linux based I suppose

Comment: I am also having this problem, any updates?

Comment: @Will At the end I was not able to solve the problem and created a new database and fed new data into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
mongod --dbpath ${path}/RateDifferenceDB
```

(this command runs mongod server with your directory as a data files directory).

Comment: I have tried your code. But I get error. For more information on error please see the Update part in question

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was version mismatch. The version i copied the versions was 3.6.x , the version i tried to restore was 4.4.

After installing 3.6.x , i copied my flat files (journal, wt...) and it worked fine.